# greek lowercase letter not italic in math mode

Tags: math-mode, greek, letters, italic

I don't know why but my greek letter eta refuses to become italic. Any ideas?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext,amsthm,mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\eta = 1$ 

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the eta looks just normal. Why does it not turn italic?

Comment: Can you please add an screenshot of your result in your question?

Comment: I have no issues with the example, the eta is italic

Comment: First of all, remove `ucs`: it does nothing useful and is obsolete.

Comment: For your case, `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` is one of the best solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `mathptmx` provides Times-like fonts, but it's a 35-year-old hack and for Greek letter it uses glyph from the slanted Symbol font.

You get better results with NewTX.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

$\eta = 1$ 

\end{document}
```

The package `ucs` is obsolete and does nothing really useful here. Also `amssymb` should not be loaded along NewTX, because this one already provides the needed symbols. Note that `amstext` is automatically loaded by `amsmath`.

[image]